# How to test function parameters when only one parameter matters to the test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have the following test written:

```
[TestCase(null, 0, 0, null, null, ExpectedException = typeof(ArgumentNullException), TestName = "VerifyThat_WhenBeginWriteHasANullBuffer_AnArgumentNullExceptionIsThrown")]
[TestCase(new byte[] {1,2,3}, -1, 0, null, null, ExpectedException = typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException), TestName = "VerifyThat_WhenBeginWriteHasANegativeSizeParameter_AnArgumentOutOfRangeExceptionIsThrown")]
[TestCase(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 4, 0, null, null, ExpectedException = typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException), TestName = "VerifyThat_WhenBeginWriteHasASizeParameterThatIsBiggerThanTheBufferSizeAndTheOffsetIsZero_AnArgumentOutOfRangeExceptionIsThrown")]
[TestCase(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 5, 1, null, null, ExpectedException = typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException), TestName = "VerifyThat_WhenBeginWriteHasASizeParameterThatIsBiggerThanTheBufferSizeMinusTheOffset_AnArgumentOutOfRangeExceptionIsThrown")]
[TestCase(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 2, -1, null, null, ExpectedException = typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException), TestName = "VerifyThat_WhenBeginWriteHasANegativeOffsetParameter_AnArgumentOutOfRangeExceptionIsThrown")]
[TestCase(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 2, 5, null, null, ExpectedException = typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException), TestName = "VerifyThat_WhenBeginWriteHasAnOffsetParameterThatIsBiggerThanTheBufferSize_AnArgumentOutOfRangeExceptionIsThrown")]
public void VerifyThat_WhenBeginWritesGivenWrongParameters_AnExceptionIsThrown(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    connectedStream.BeginWrite(buffer, offset, size, callback, state);
}
```

I am currently calling the BeginWrite function with the invalid parameter and random valid parameters.
Am I doing the right thing here? Is there a better way to supply valid parameters?

EDIT:
In this case the validity of the tested parameter depands on the valid parameters.
For example offset is invalid whenever it is  negative or whenever it is bigger than buffer size minus the offset. The fact that the test passes for one case where the offset is bigger than buffer size minus the offset or negative doesn't prove that the method will always throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException.  I can always miss something.
It's always better to check multiple inputs than just once.
Is there a way to do so automatically?

EDIT 2:
Could [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) be my solution?

EDIT 3:
[AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) doesn't have a silverlight port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test the reaction to an invalid argument, you should make all the others valid to avoid false positives where a different argument causes the failure.

As to how to supply those valid parameters, do it just like you do in any other situation where you don't really care about what the value is and just use something that works.

You're testing that the method throws when you feed it one specific invalid parameter, and all the others are valid. As long as the other arguments meet your definition of valid, you're testing the right thing, so don't worry much about how to get the values.

Comment: In this case the validity of the tested parameter depands on the valid parameters. For example offset is invalid whenever it is  negative or whenever it is bigger than buffer size minus the offset. The fact that the test passes for one case where the offset is bigger than buffer size minus the offset or negative doesn't prove that the method will always throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I can always miss something. It's always better to check multiple inputs than just once. Is there a way to do so automatically?

Answer (score 2):

**The technical part.**

NUnit 2.5 has some new attributes to help automating test case generation:

- [`Range`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=range&r=2.5) - generate multiple test cases by using all numerical values specified in the range for a parameter.
- [`Values`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=values&r=2.5) - similar to `Range`, where you can specify a list of individual values instead of a numerical range.
- [`ValueSource`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=valueSource&r=2.5) - specify a function to generate list of `Values`.
- [`TestCaseSoucre`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) - specify a function to generate list of `TestCase`. Every piece of detail can be customized.

`Range`, `Values` and `ValueSource` applies to a single parameter. Each parameter can use its own value attribute.

The function used for `ValueSource` and `TestCaseSource` is called *very early, probably before* `TestFixtureSetUp`. Refer to documentation for usage.

**Example.**

- The byte array `buffer` could use a `ValueSource` function which specifies the buffer size, so that you can try larger arrays without too much typing.
- For a given `buffer`, the valid range for `size` is anywhere from 1 up to the size of the buffer.
- For a given `buffer` and `size`, the valid range for `offset` is from zero up to *size minus size (I'll leave this one for you; it's a consecutive range)*
- Anything else is out of range.

**Side note.** The four conditions stated above together become a [`Theory`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=theory&r=2.5) and NUnit have direct support for testing theories. When using a theory, you can write your test case function once and cover both the good arguments and bad arguments.

---

**The test philosophy part.**

- When you know of multiple test approaches (or criteria), always take them all, and within each approach try a reasonable set of test cases.
- Use automated test case generation to your maximal benefit.
- Without access to the source code (of the software-under-test) and knowing our test code coverage, we cannot decide whether we are missing something. This is why white-box testing is necessary if a certain level of guarantee is needed.